# Is importing the same font multiple times from different sources harmful?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2, google-font-api, google-fonts

**Problem:**
In my HTML file, I have:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
```

I want the font to be available to users who can't access `fonts.googleapis.com` but can access my website.

**Solution I went with:**
I provide a locally-hosted alternative by following the steps [here in google-webfonts.helper](https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts/roboto?subsets=greek-ext,latin-ext,vietnamese,cyrillic-ext,latin,cyrillic,greek). To be specific:

1. I've created a file `roboto.css` under my `/assets` folder and pasted the code in step 3 in the link above.
2. Downloaded the fonts under `/assets/fonts`.
3. Added to `index.html`: `<link href="/assets/roboto.css" rel="stylesheet">`

To confirm: I still have the initial google fonts. I.e., my `index.html` has:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/assets/roboto.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**Question(s):**
(1) Is double-importing that way harmful in anyway?
(2) Is what I'm doing right?
(3) Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: To see if it is harmfull check you devtools and see if both urls are used to load the fonts. Also note that more people will have `font.googleapis..` url to roboto already cached as it is used quite a lot

Comment: (1) How to check that exactly? By checking the network tab, I see: the 2 css files (from google & local `assets/roboto.css`, and 2 fonts being downloaded from the local `/assets`, one for regular and one for 500 (which I totally don't understand why. Why is the 300 not being loaded? Because not used or something?). (2) Yes, I know. But I have a use-case for some people who can't access google (e.g., if my website is served in a private network).